# How to caption a smartdiagram figure?

Tags: captions, smartdiagram

I am using smartdiagram to make a figure in my document. I want to know how can I caption this figure. I am pasting sample code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\caption{Cycle of Interaction}
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{Cycle of Environment,
      Look, Plan, Act}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's a `\begin{document}` missing

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: ... and now put that `\begin{document}` after `\usepackage{smartdiagram}` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Argh.. Me tex noob. 
LOL :)
Thanks man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\smartdiagram` macro does not work as a `float` environment etc. so `caption` is useless here, but since a diagram works as a `figure` basically, `\captionof{figure}{Cycle of Interaction}` should be sufficient.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\captionof{figure}{Cycle of Interaction}
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{Cycle of Environment,
      Look, Plan, Act}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

If `figure` isn't the correct name, there are basically two ways to improve this:

1. Use `\captionsetup` to provide another `name=Diagram`, for example

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{smartdiagram}
   \usepackage{caption}



   \begin{document}
   \begin{center}
   \captionsetup[figure]{name=Diagram}
   \captionof{figure}{Cycle of Interaction}
   \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{Cycle of Environment,
     Look, Plan, Act}
   \end{center}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Define a new floating environment, say, `diag`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}


   \usepackage{smartdiagram}
   \usepackage{newfloat}
   \usepackage{caption}


   \DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=diag,placement={!ht},name=Diagram]{diag}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{center}
   \captionof{diag}{Cycle of Interaction}
   \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{Cycle of Environment,
     Look, Plan, Act}
   \end{center}
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

I prefer the 2nd way with an extra floating environment, but that is a matter of taste.

Comment: great--was looking for this ``````\begin{center}
\captionof{figure}{Cycle of Interaction}
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{Cycle of Environment,
      Look, Plan, Act}
\end{center}`````````````````````````````````